How to approach eigenvalue problem with Schur complement?
In the context of preconditioning saddle point problems (for instance, arising from PDEs) people are interested in solving (generalised) eigenvalue problems associated with the Schur complement $BA^{-1}B^T$, where $A,B$ are as usual coming from the saddle point formulation:
\begin{pmatrix} A & B^T \\ B & 0 \end{pmatrix}
Say that the eigenvalue problem to be solved looks as follows: $$BA^{-1} B^T x = \lambda Cx$$
How are people solving this? I would like to use SLEPc (based on PETSc), and the only solution I can think of is to really build the Schur complement itself and pass it to one of SLEPc solvers. Are there smarter ways to tackle this problem, i.e. without building the Schur complement explicitly?

You could just implement an operator that performs multiplication with $BA^{-1}B^T$, where $z=A^{-1}y$ is not computed and instead $Az = y$ is solved with your favorite solver. Example: I want to compute $w = BA^{-1}B^Tx$. First compute $y=B^Tx$, then solve $Az=y$, then compute $w=Bz$. Of course you can use only two vectors $x$ and $y$ and ping-pong them, i.e., $z$ reuses the same memory as $x$ and $w$ reuses the same memory as $y$. If $A$ is sufficiently small and you call this operator sufficiently often it may make sense to compute a factorization $A=LU$ or $A=LL^T$ if it's spd.

I thought about that, i.e to just work with the action of the operator in the way you proposed. However, it looks to me that SLEPc requires PETSc matrices to be given @lightxbulb

See this: https://petsc.org/release/manualpages/Mat/Mat/
More specifically:
Abstract PETSc matrix object used to manage all linear operators in PETSc, even those without an explicit sparse representation (such as matrix-free operators).

Specifically, you need to use the MatShell matrix type.
